# is the embedding $\mathrm{Sp}_{2m}(p)\leqslant S_{p^m-1}$ possible?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, classical-groups

Is the following embedding possible?

$\mathrm{Sp}_{2m}(p)\leqslant S_{p^m-1}$ where $S_{p^m-1}$ is a symmetric group and $p$ is prime. I see that when $p=3$ and $m=3$, the order of the former does divide the order of the latter. I was also thinking along the lines of $\mathrm{PSp}$ being simple except for finite cases but haven't gotten an answer. I feel that it is not possible, though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The smallest degrees of the faithful permutation representations of the finite simple groups are listed in Table 4.5 of [On the maximum orders of elements of finite almost simple groups and primitive permutation groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5166) by Guest, Morris, Praeger, and Spiga.

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSp{PSp}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$With a couple of small exceptions, for $\PSp(2m,q)$ with $m \ge 2$, the minimum degree is $(q^{2m}-1)/(q-1)$ for $q \ne 2$ and $2^{m-1}(2^m-1)$ when $q=2$.

So $\Sp(2m,2)$ has no proper subgroup of index less than this, and so it cannot have a faithful permutation representation of smaller degree.

I think the minimum degree for $\Sp(2m,q)$ is probably $q^{2m}-1$ for $q$ odd.

Comment: So the minimum degree is achieved by the tautological representation, in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$Derek's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/447991) is definitive. I think, at least for $p> 3$ odd, we can also see that the answer is no by considering the irreducible characters of $\Sp(2m,p)$. The smallest non-trivial irreducible character degrees are $\frac{p^{m}-1}{2}$ and $\frac{p^{m}+1}{2}$, coming from the so-called Weil representations. One of these (the one whose degree is odd) contains the central involution in its kernel, and the other represents the central involution by $-I$. Neither of these characters is rational-valued, and all other non-trivial irreducible characters (not algebraically conjugate to either of these) have degree at least $p^{m}-1$. On the other hand, the symmetric group $S_{p^{m}-1}$ has a faithful irreducible rational valued character of degree $p^{m}-2$, while $\Sp(2m,p)$ has no faithful rational-valued character (irreducible or not) of degree $p^{m}-2$.